# Remote boot command / boot via network call

Tags: networking, boot

Is it possible to boot another computer (Windows preferrably) with a special network command?

Use case (let's call this command `remote boot`):

- ComputerA at home is switched off or in standby
  (but `remote boot` is enabled)
- ComputerB with low energy (e.g. RaspberryPi, running LinuxDebian) is listening on an encrypted channel for instructions
- once ComputerB receives (an authorized) `remote boot ComputerA`, he forwards it to ComputerA
  (command could come from smartphone)
- ComputerA boots up
- command `remote boot` may only be accepted within local network

I couldn't find anything allowing this, at most `remote restart`, which isn't quite, what I'm looking for.

I sense, this might involve communicating with BIOS. I have experience programming my own TCP/IP server/client connection, but can't imagine how to apply this to such a thing like `remote boot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called Wake On Lan (WOL). If you don't know WOL please read about it yourself on wikipedia or any other source you trust ;-)

There are a few requirements your Devices need to fit if you wana use WOL.

1. Your Networkcard and OS on the Remote Computer must know WOL (Windows does fit these needs, if your Networkcard (NIC) does you can find out be either searching for it on your PC, on the internet or asking the Manufacturer of your NIC.
2. Your PC must be connected over LAN.
3. You need a Tool (most of the Time a VNC Client or Remote Desktop Client) which is able to send the WOL command to xour Remote PC.

Another way to launch your PC from Remote is calling someone and ask him/her to start the PC or maybe a time based boot may also fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks, @konqui, that's exactly what I was looking for. Source code for that is available plenty online.